# Chances of miscounting an even number of times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We count from 1 to n ∈ N, we have constant p chance of miscounting at each number.

1) What is the chance of us miscounting an even number of times?

2) What is the chance of us miscounting an even of number of times but this number of miscounting isn't 0?

For the 1st, I assumed for simplicity's sake that n is even, our options are p^2, p^4, ..., p^n I believe this should be something with (n choose 2k) for sure.

For the 2nd, I'm sure it'll just be what we got in #1 - p^n, but this might just be wrong because we're not sure this equality can always be between 0 and 1.

Comment: In question 1, why are you not taking into account the probability of counting correctly?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier i did not, was not supposed to assume anything about the parity of n?

Comment: No that's actually a very good thing to make assumptions that make your life easier to get started, but I mean the probability of miscounting twice and then counting correctly all the way to $n$ is **not** $p^2$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier oh you're right actually, the probability of miscounting exactly twice is p^2 times (1-p^(n-2)) , since the n-2 numbers need to be counted properly, and that has probability n-2

Comment: @ArnaudMortier so since we only want even miscounts will it be something like (n choose 2k) times (p^2k) times (1-p^(n-2k)) i assume?

Comment: That's almost correct, the exponent $n-2$ is not supposed to be exactly where you put it.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier ahh, the power should for (1-p) as a whole, not just p, rookie mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of times that we miscount. Then $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ is a Binomially distributed random variable with probability of success $p$ i.e.
$$
P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
Let
$$
G(t)=Et^X=\sum_{k=0}^n P(X=k)t^k=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(pt)^k(1-p)^{n-k}=(1-p+pt)^n
$$
be the probability generating function of $X$ where we have used the binomial theorem in the last equality. Notice that
$$
G(1)+G(-1)=\sum_{k=0}^n P(X=k)+ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k P(X=k)=2\sum_{\text{k even}} P(X=k)
$$
So the probability we miscount an even number of times is given by
$$
\frac{1+(1-2p)^n}{2}=\frac{G(1)+G(-1)}{2}=\sum_{\text{k even}} P(X=k)
$$